# How to prove the equivalency of the following two optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

The following two problems are equivalent

(P1) $\underset{\mathbf x}{\arg\min}\,\, f(\mathbf x)+g(\mathbf x)$

(P2) $\underset{\mathbf x,y}{\arg\min}\,\, f(\mathbf x)+y\quad \quad \text{s.t.}\,\,\, g(\mathbf x)\leq y$

I want to know how to prove it rigorously.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: show that for a solution of (2) the constraint is satisfied with equality

Comment: @daw, Sorry, I could not follow you. Could you provide more details? Thanks a lot.